# Prove that any prime p > 3 is either of the form 6k + 1 or of the form 6k + 5 for some integer k.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I followed these steps
Assume $p$ is an arbitrary prime and $p > 3$,then $p$ can be written in form of,
$$p=6k+r,r ∈\left\{0,1,2,3,4,5\right\}$$
Then for $r∈\left\{0,2,3,4\right\}$ Asumption contradicts.
Therefore $r=1$ or $r=5$
My problem is when for $r∈\left\{0,2,3,4\right\}$ Assumption contradicts, How we say certainly any prime is either form $6k+1$ or $6k+5$?

Comment: Well, any number of the form $6k+2$ is even, for example.  Can you handle the other cases?

Comment: Of course, my problem is, If for $r∈\left\{0,2,3,4\right\}$ asumption contradicts.then how we certainly say r=1 or r=5.